# Loading openvino python library on Raspebrry pi 4

Tags: python, openvino

After followign the guides (and coming through the github trackers), I was able to get OpenVINO to install on my pi4 and can run /opt/intel/openvino/bin/armv7l/Release/object_detection_sample_ssd  successfully using my own trained model.

I used the follow cmake command most recently, but I've done pretty much all iterations I could find on the several instruction pages.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release /
      -DENABLE_SSE42=OFF /
      -DTHREADING=SEQ /
      -DENABLE_GNA=OFF /
      -DENABLE_PYTHON=ON /
      -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python3 /
      -DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7m.so /
      -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7m /
      -NGRAPH_PYTHON_BUILD_ENABLE=ON /
      -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-latomic /
      -DOPENCV_EXTRA_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-latomic /
      -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local  /
      .. && make
```

When I try one of the python examples I get

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ngraph'
```

Looking more into it now and it appears the issue is the "setupvars.sh" script not calling into the right directory. I was able to get the module openvino to load by adjusting the export path. I must say the amount of documentation that is, quite frankly all over the place and seems to have wrong directory structures left and right.

Answer (score 0):

As of right now, the builds for the Raspberry Pi are not being made with NGRAPH compiled. The user has to compile it themselves from scratch per this thread. https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Distribution-of-OpenVINO/No-ngraph-bindings-for-python-in-raspbian-distribution/m-p/1263401#M23093

The comment by the Intel "Support" is wrong and won't work on new builds.

Comment: You mentioned that you could run verification script (/opt/intel/openvino/bin/armv7l/Release/object_detection_sample_ssd) but unable to run one of the python examples.

Comment: As such, we replicated your issue on our build from source setup with the Classification Python demo. We faced the same “ModuleNotFoundError” as you faced.

Comment: Upon setting all the environment variables, we were able to run the demo successfully. That was the reason we provided the previous solution to you.

Comment: However, we overlooked the fact that Python demo script does not import ngraph module in the script. We apologize for our oversight.

Comment: We revalidated with Object Detection Demo (which imports ngraph module) and we are seeing the same error again.

Comment: ngraph is not included in Intel distribution for Raspberry Pi, and now we are still investigating whether it is possible to build ngraph module with the open source version of OpenVINO. We will update you once we have clarified this.

Comment: @IntelSupport please **edit & update** accordingly your answer above, instead of engaging with such long discussions in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the steps below for building Open Source OpenVINO™ Toolkit for Raspbian OS:

1. Set up build environment and install build tools

   `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`

   `sudo apt install build-essential`
2. Install CMake from source

   `cd ~/`

   `wget https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.14.4/cmake-3.14.4.tar.gz`

   `tar xvzf cmake-3.14.4.tar.gz`

   `cd ~/cmake-3.14.4`

   `./bootstrap`

   `make -j4 && sudo make install`
3. Install OpenCV from source

   `sudo apt install git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev python3-scipy libatlas-base-dev`

   `cd ~/`

   `git clone --depth 1 --branch 4.5.2 https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git`

   `cd opencv && mkdir build && cd build`

   `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local ..`

   `make -j4 && sudo make install`
4. Download source code and install dependencies

   `cd ~/`

   `git clone --depth 1 --branch 2021.3 https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/openvino.git`

   `cd ~/openvino`

   `git submodule update --init --recursive`

   `sh ./install_build_dependencies.sh`

   `cd ~/openvino/inference-engine/ie_bridges/python/`

   `pip3 install -r requirements.txt`
5. Start CMake build

   `export OpenCV_DIR=/usr/local/lib/cmake/opencv4`

   `cd ~/openvino`

   `mkdir build && cd build`

   `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \`

   `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/home/pi/openvino_dist \`

   `-DENABLE_MKL_DNN=OFF \`

   `-DENABLE_CLDNN=OFF \`

   `-DENABLE_GNA=OFF \`

   `-DENABLE_SSE42=OFF \`

   `-DTHREADING=SEQ \`

   `-DENABLE_OPENCV=OFF \`

   `-DNGRAPH_PYTHON_BUILD_ENABLE=ON \`

   `-DNGRAPH_ONNX_IMPORT_ENABLE=ON \`

   `-DENABLE_PYTHON=ON \`

   `-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3.7) \`

   `-DPYTHON_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpython3.7m.so \`

   `-DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/include/python3.7 \`

   `-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-latomic ..`

   `make -j4 && sudo make install`
6. Configure the Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2 Linux USB Driver

   `sudo usermod -a -G users "$(whoami)"`

   `source /home/pi/openvino_dist/bin/setupvars.sh`

   `sh /home/pi/openvino_dist/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh`
7. Verify nGraph module binding to Python

   `cd /home/pi/openvino_dist/deployment_tools/inference_engine/samples/python/object_detection_sample_ssd`

   `python3 object_detection_sample_ssd.py -h`